# Jquery setTimeout on popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to set the opening time for a popup?

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        mgsjQuery(window).load(function () {
            if(mgsjQuery(window).width() > 991) {
                if(getCookie('newsletter')!='nevershow'){
                    if (mgsjQuery('#newsletter').length) {
                        mgsjQuery.magnificPopup.open({
                            items: {
                                src: '#newsletter' 
                            },
                            type: 'inline'
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

I think that i should include the code below, but i do not know where?

```
setTimeout( NAME, 8000 );
```

Comment: When would you like to open the popup? After a certain event? On page load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [setTimeout method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) documentation.

So where the NAME is, you should insert your function name or anonymous function.

So in your case it'll be something like:

```
mgsjQuery(window).load(function () {
  if(mgsjQuery(window).width() > 991) {
    if(getCookie('newsletter')!='nevershow'){
      if (mgsjQuery('#newsletter').length) {
        setTimeout(function(){  // <- Inserted - below code will run after 8 seconds
          mgsjQuery.magnificPopup.open({
            items: {
              src: '#newsletter' 
            },
            type: 'inline'
          });
        }, 8000);   // <- Inserted 8000 ms = 8 sec.
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to wait some time before the popup opens, you can use **delay()**. You can call the method after the .open()

Like this:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    mgsjQuery(window).load(function () {
        if(mgsjQuery(window).width() > 991) {
            if(getCookie('newsletter')!='nevershow'){
                if (mgsjQuery('#newsletter').length) {
                    mgsjQuery.magnificPopup.open({
                        items: {
                            src: '#newsletter' 
                        },
                        type: 'inline'
                    }).delay(1000);
                }
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

In this case, the delay function will wait 1 second (the parameter is given in miliseconds) before opening the popup.